# cordova angularjs mobile app failing to retrieve data from success response callback (network call)?

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova

I have working angular js application from the browser, through which able to retrieve successfully data from the $http network call,

but the same appliction when i have done mobile package with cordova (either android/ios in both cases), unable to retrieve the data from success response callback with the network call.

configurations are listed below:
corodva 6.4.0 version, 
android marshmallow version,
xcode have 8.2.1 version & simulator of 10.2 version,

```
    $http({
    method : 'POST',
    withCredentials : true,
    headers : {
        'X-IBM-Client-ID' : "xxx",
        'X-IBM-Client-Secret' : "xxx",
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    },
    data : {},
    url : "xxx",
    }).success(function(data) {
        console.log("in successful call back json data:"+JSON.stringify(data)+" data:"+data);   
    }).error(function(data){
        console.log("error due to "+ data);
    });
```

let me know if any suggestions how to proceed on this.

thanks & regards,
vasu.

Comment: remove `withCredentials : true,` . Some cors error may stop here

Answer (score 0):

remove `comma` after `url: "xxx"` and use `.then` instead of `success` and `error`

```
$http({
method : 'POST',
withCredentials : true,
headers : {
    'X-IBM-Client-ID' : "xxx",
    'X-IBM-Client-Secret' : "xxx",
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
},
data : {},
url : "xxx"
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log("in successful call back json data:"+JSON.stringify(data)+" data:"+data);   
}, function(error){
    console.log("error due to "+ error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, but even above one is not working out. any any suggestions /alternative approach ???? plz let me know on this.

Comment: none of the errors app is pointing, simply success response callback without data, it looks like something is blocking the data which i am not getting, even its not pointing out like CORS (cross origin requests block) as well.